# The limits of integral for the joint probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> The joint probability density function of $X$ and $Y$ is given by
>
> $$f(x,y)=c(y^2 - 36x^2)e^{-y}, \quad \text{ for }  -y/6 < x < y/6,\,\, 0 < y < \infty$$
>   Find $c$ and the expected value of $X$:

That's my question that I have an issue.

I know how can I find $c$ and expected value of $X$ or $Y$ for joint pdf, when the intervals are like: $0 < x < 3 , 0 < y < 5$. I know the limits $0$ to $3$ and $0$ to $5$. However, I could not specify the limits of integral for these intervals.

Could you please help me about it? I need brief explanation why it is like this, not any answers.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a typo, you claim the restriction is $y/6 < x < y/6$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the restriction is $-y/6<x<y/6$. So it needs to be true that
$x<y/6$ **and** $-y/6<x$. This is the same as $y>-6x$ **and** $y<6x$.  Graph these two inequalities for yourself and notice that you are interested in the region between the two lines. Thus, one possible way to do it is to integrate over $y$ first then $x$. This would be
$$\int_0^\infty\int_{-6x}^{6x}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dydx.$$
This is equal to 1, since you are integrating over all possible values of $x$,$y$.